# Find roots of $x^3-(2\sqrt 2+i)x^2 + (4+2i\sqrt 2)x-4i=0$ knowing that at least one of the roots is from the set $\{i, -i\}.$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find roots of
>   $$x^3-(2\sqrt 2+i)x^2 + (4+2i\sqrt 2)x-4i=0$$ 
>   knowing that at least one of the roots is from the set $\{i, -i\}$. Write each root in polar form.

I know that since at least one root is from this set, hence ${x}^2 + 1 $ will be a divisor of my initial equation. Usually, I would divide the first one by the second but I came across some difficulties and I don't know what to do.

[EDIT] My assumption was wrong.

Comment: "hence $x^2+1$ will be a divisor" is not necessarily true, the coefficients are complex. Check which of $i,-i$ is indeed a root.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. First verify whether $x_0=i$ **or** $x_0=-i$ is a root ($x^2+1$ is a divisor of the given polynomial iff $x_0=i$ **and** $x_0=-i$ are roots):
$$(\pm i)^3-(2\sqrt 2+i)(\pm i)^2 + (4+2i\sqrt 2)(\pm i)-4i=0 ?$$
Then divide the cubic polynomial by $x-x_0$. The quotient will be a quadratic polynomial which should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

"I know that since at least one root is from this set, hence $x^2+1$ will be a divisor of my initial equation." This is an incorrect statement—but incorrect for a very interesting and educational reason.

The relevant fact is: if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in a field $F$, and $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$ (in some extension of $F$), then $p(x)$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.

You tried to apply this with $\alpha=i$ (say); but the coefficients of the given polynomial are not in $\Bbb R$, so this fact doesn't concern the minimial polynomial $x^2+1$ of $i$ over $\Bbb R$; rather, the coefficients of our $p(x)$ are defined over $\Bbb C$, and so it is the minimal polynomial $x-i$ of $i$ over $\Bbb C$ that is relevant. In other words, we have just (re)learned that $x-i$ divides $p(x)$ (if it is $i$ that is the root of $p(x)$).

Here's an extreme example of the same fallacy: since $\sqrt[4]2$ is a root of $x-\sqrt[4]2$, does it then follow that $x^4-2$ divides $x-\sqrt[4]2$?

Comment: Long way for "it is not said that $i$ and $-i$ are both roots".

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped me understand my mistake. With your hints and suggestions I was able to find the other roots
[image: solution]

Comment: This would be easier to read if you wrote it with MathJax.

Comment: Is something unclear?